# How would I Dynamically Assign Self-referencing onClick to table of buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

So I've just started learning JS and am stuck on this problem. I've created a table of buttons using JS which translates to this in HTML:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%; border: none;">
<tr>
    <td class="emptyBorder">
        <button class="gridButton" id="button0x0y"></button></td>
    <td class="emptyBorder">
        <button class="gridButton" id="button0x1y"></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="emptyBorder">
        <button class="gridButton" id="button1x0y"></button></td>
    <td class="emptyBorder">
        <button class="gridButton" id="button1x1y"></button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to give each of them an onClick that cycles only their own color between 3 different colors. I tried assigning this onClick to each of them when I created them in my JS code, but was running into problems there so I separated that functionality into a new function, which is:

```
function addOnclickToTable(x, y){
    for( var i = 0; i < x; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = 0; j < y; j++ ) {
            var thisId = buttonIDFromXY(i,j); // returns "button{i}x{j}y"
            var button = document.getElementById(thisId);
            button.onclick = function() {cycleBackgroundColor(thisID);}; // Changes background color of the element with the given ID
        }
    }
}
```

This assigns "onclick = cycleBackgroundColor('button1x1y')" to each of the buttons. It seems that the value of **thisID** is saved in the JS and referenced as its last known value when it is called later on. Is there a way to create a new instance of it in place? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this way.

```js
var table = document.querySelector('table');
var buttons = [].slice.call(table.querySelectorAll('.gridButton'));
table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if(buttons.indexOf(target) > -1) {
    var id = target.id;

    console.log(id, target);
    // target is your button and id its id
    // do your color circle thing here
    // you could bind the button as `this` to your circle function
    // circleBackgroundColor().bind(target);
    // inside of circleBackgroundColor this.id will give you the button id and this will give you the button.
  }
});
```

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 100%; border: none;">
<tr>
    <td class="emptyBorder">
        <button class="gridButton" id="button0x0y"></button></td>
    <td class="emptyBorder">
        <button class="gridButton" id="button0x1y"></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="emptyBorder">
        <button class="gridButton" id="button1x0y"></button></td>
    <td class="emptyBorder">
        <button class="gridButton" id="button1x1y"></button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```